# Conditionally merge two streams with RxJs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two server calls to made to get some response in my stream. But if the first call returns with some data I don't want to execute the second call. I couldn't find a proper operator or a combination of operators to do the cancelation (I don't want to throw an error btw) of the second request on the success of the first one.

I also tried defaultIfEmpty but looked like a hack and I didn't like it.

I created a StackBlitz example you can check it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ozgkjj) but I am not sure it is a good practice or not. So basically I need a conditional concatMap.

If you know how to do it with available operators without creating a new one, I really like to hear your approaches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, Mark van Straten. Here is the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kxf5ac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your first async request is of type `Observable<T>` and only returns a value `T` on success and otherwise just completes without emitting a value you can use a simple `.concat()` instead:

```
firstAsyncCall()
  .concat(secondAsyncCall())
  .take(1)
```

The `.take(1)` will make sure the `secondAsyncCall()` will not be invoked if the `firstAsyncCall` returns (at least) 1 value.

Comment: Brilliant and elegant

Comment: Wow, yes this is really simple. That is actually what I was looking for. Thanks! Still, it is not intuitive for me. `take(1)` is after `concat()` and could cancel it. I should learn more about the executions of pipes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to stop the stream when the value doesn't suit you :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1uvrgf?file=index.ts

```
const interval$ = interval(100);

interval$.pipe(
  filter(val => val % 10 === 0),
  take(10),
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my first source is just an async API call. If I filter on the response not being there it won't fire the second request if the first call returns null right?

Comment: If you put the right condition yes, it won't send a second request. If the condition in the filter isn't met, any operator following it (or the subscribe) won't be ran.

Comment: @UgurKorfali (That's why you see 0 to 90 by the way, since the `take` operator is after it, it will only trigger when the condition is met)

Comment: `const subscribe = source1$.pipe(
  filter(x => x !== null),
  concatMap(() => source2$ )
).subscribe(console.log);`

By this way, I can't get the response of the firstSource$, If I got it correct

Comment: In this case, if `source1$` doesn't return null, you will see a console log. Otherwise, you won't see a console log. So you do get the result of the first request (which is made), it's just stopped before `concatMap`.

Comment: But the thing is if it returns null I want to see the response of the second call, if it does not then see the response of the first call. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: you can `tap` before the `filter` if it's only for a console log, otherwise replace `filter` with `concatMap(val => val === null ? of(val) : source2$)` : it's dirtier but it does what you want.

Comment: That is exactly what I have in my StackBlitz example. I updated the link it was incorrect before. I also found this solution a bit dirty. Thanks anyways